# Is data will be available in temptable after disconnecting a database?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have created a `.p` which contain connect `db` statement  after that I'm running a `.p` which is creating a `temptable` after that, database will be a disconnected. Will data be available in `temptable` after disconnecting from the database?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will be available. Data that is collected in a temp-table is not linked to the DB and can be manipulated freely. Conversely, in order to make actual CHANGES to your db, you need to assign those values back, probably by setting another connection and doing that.